# Unable to instantiate activity: ComponentInfo java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Directory "."

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk

I've extensively searched for this error in multiple stackoverflow questions as well as other sites but the log message I get is slightly different from whatever I've seen before.

The difference is this:

12-05 10:45:11.111: E/AndroidRuntime(2643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 10:45:11.111: E/AndroidRuntime(2643): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo {com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.Splash" on path: DexPathList[[**directory "."**],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]

All other questions I've seen generally have some apk path present in the DexPathlist but in my case, there's nothing.

The relevant part of the manifest is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:hasCode="false" android:requiredForAllUsers="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
...
```

I've tried all the suggestions on other questions (i.e. enabling the Android Private Libraries and Android Dependencies under the Order and Export tab, cleaning and rebuilding project) but nothing seems to work! I've even created a new project and copied everything over but I still get the same issue in the new project.

What's most confusing is that this happened fairly spontaneously. I had come back to the project after some time and ran it after adding in a new image to use for my splash screen. The only thing that comes to mind is that when I initially uploaded an image it was titled "sr-splash.jpg" which was rejected due to the dash. So I refactored/renamed it to "sr_splash.jpg" and updated. Immediately after this one change, I ran the project and started running into this issue but it seems unlikely that any part of this would have something to do with the error but just thought I'd mention it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check on Proguard settings? It might be the culprit.

Comment: Where is the *file* part of your manifest? That part is also relevant.

Comment: @Halim If you're referring to the project.properties file, then the only line present there apart from the comments is "target=android-19"

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Sorry, what do you mean by the "file" part?

Comment: @RizJa not project properties but proguard.txt or proguard.pro or something like that.

Comment: Also you should not try only clean and rebuild. But you should try Make Project too.

Comment: The indication of where your class resides is in the *<file/>* tag

Comment: @Halim I don't have proguard enabled. The proguard-project.txt file has the following noted: "# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties # to define the proguard.config property as described in that file." The project.properties has the line that enables it commented out.

Comment: @Halim Regarding "Make Project", I don't see any such option in Eclipse

Comment: Have you added the other activity to manifest file? @RizJa

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I'm not sure what tag you're referring to. I've never used a file tag in my manifest.

Comment: @Hourglass Which other activity? I have all the activities defined below the splash one.. just didn't include them above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... it was this line:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:hasCode="false" android:requiredForAllUsers="true">
```

I removed

```
android:hasCode="false"
```

and it started running correctly.